# Webserver status set to down after installing PHP on the webserver

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, webserver, haproxy

After I install php 8.0 on my webserver running apache 2.4.53 on ubuntu 20.04, my haproxy config on a pfsense router says the webserver is down. Even though apache is running fine.

I know its the main cause because after I uninstall php 8.0 the webserver is up and accessible according to haproxy.

The problem is, that I can't load content without having php installed on the webserver, but if I have it installed, the webserver isn't accessible from the designated ip.

I have tried reading the haproxy error log, but I can't find it. Also tried to reinstall the haproxy config but this also didn't work. In haproxy status overiew it also gives the error: Layer 7 wrong status: internal server error, googling this didn't give much results.

Comment: _"Layer 7 wrong status: internal server error"_ - sounds like it got a 500 status code when making an HTTP request to Apache, and therefor thinks it was down? Can you directly access any resources on your Apache without the proxy?

Comment: Hi there, yes I can access the resources without the proxy

Comment: What do the error logs say, about the reason for the 500 error?

Comment: I just wanted to make a notice that it is fixed, for any other noobs like me running into this issue: check the perms for the www folder. I made apache the owner and then the problem was fixed!